# Selenium-webdriver zip issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rubyzip

Yesterday my rspec +selenium was running fine. Today when i ran tests i got:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Zip::File
 # /home/mygemsetpathd/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:21:in `unzip'
```

Then i updates selenium-webdriver to 2.39.0 but error is the same. 
I have gem 'zip' and gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 1.0", require: 'zip' in my Gemfile.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it - so if some1 have the same issue: if your bundle update updated rubyzip to 1.1.0 then you should remove gem 'zip' from your Gemfile - then it works perfectly.